# How to read from a replicaset mongo by mongodb-erlang

Tags: mongodb, erlang

```
1. {ok,P}= mongoc:connect({rs, <<"dev_mongodb">>, [ "dev_mongodb001:27017", "dev_mongodb002:27017"]}, [{name, mongopool}, {register, mongotopology}, { rp_mode, primary},{ rp_tags, [{tag,1}]}], [{login, <<"root">>}, {password, <<"mongoadmin">>}, {database, <<"admin">>}]).
2. {ok, Pool} = mc_topology:get_pool(P, []).
3. mongoc:find(Pool, {<<"DoctorLBS">>, <<"mongoMessage">>}, #{<<"type">> => <<"5">>}).
```

I used latest version in github, and got an error at step 3.[image]

It seems my selector is not valid, is there any example of how to use mongodb-erlang ?

My mongodb version is 3.2.6, auth type is SCRAM-SHA1.

```
mongoc:find(Pool, <<"mongoMessage">>, #{<<"type">> => <<"5">>}).
```

I tried this in rs and single mode, still got this error.
Is there any other simple way to connect and read? 
I just need to read some data once from mongo when my erlang program start, no other actions.

Answer (score 0):

Todays version of mongo does not support tuple colldb due to new query api introduced in mongo 2.6 
You should connect to `DoctorLBS` database instead, and than use

```
mongoc:find(Pool,  <<"mongoMessage">>, #{<<"type">> => <<"5">>}).
```